# Mutually singular measure corollary

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is an exercise in Royden and Fitzpatrick Real Analysis.

Let $\mu$ be a measure and $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ be mutually singular measures on a measurable space $(X, \mu)$ for which $\mu = \mu_1 - \mu_2$. Show that $\mu_2 = 0$.

I'm quite beginner and have difficulty to understand the definitions well.
First it seems that $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are not necessarily signed measures. Is this the meaning of the question's requirement: "for any measurable subset $E \subset X$ we have $\mu_2(E) = 0$"

by definition of singularity of measures there exists measurable subsets of $X$ , such that $X= A\cup A^c$ with $\mu_1(A)=0=\mu_2(A^c)$. How do I use this to show the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined, all of them are measures, not signed measures.

> Is this the meaning of the question's requirement: "for any measurable subset E⊂X we have μ2(E)=0"

Yes.  However, since $\mu_2$ is a measure, not a signed measure, it's enough to show $\mu_2(X) = 0.$  [If you haven't proven it before, show that this property suffices to show $\mu_2=0.$]

As for your final question, you should evaluate $\mu(A)$ for the set $A$ you defined.

Comment: Would this argument work to prove it?:
$$\mu(A) = \mu_1(A)-\mu_2(A) = -\mu_2(A) = \mu_2(A^c)-\mu_2(X) =-\mu_2(X) $$
given that $$\mu(A) = -\mu_2(X) \geq 0 $$ by def. of $\mu_2(X) \geq 0$ it must be the case that $$\mu_2(X) = 0$$

Comment: @stat That works.  Depending on how rigorous you want it, you could make the middle line $-\mu_2(X) = \mu(A) \geq 0$ (which more directly implies what you're arguing is $\geq 0$) but the logic's all there.